# Selecting from two tables where two given dates are not between two others.

Tags: mysql

Imagine this simple database table structure.

```
ROOM
id | id_HOTEL | id_PRICE

BOOKING
id | id_ROOM | date_from | date_to
```

I need to select rooms with id_HOTEL=1 and id_PRICE=1 from ROOM and the corresponding rooms from BOOKING where two given dates aren't overlapping date_from and date_to.

How can I write this SQL query?

Comment: What two given date? Can you share a sample with the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOKING AS b
WHERE b.ID_ROOM IN
    ( SELECT r.ID
     FROM ROOM AS r
     WHERE r.ID_HOTEL = 1
       AND r.ID_PRICE = 1)
  AND b.DATE_FROM NOT BETWEEN :GIVEN_DATE_FROM AND :GIVEN_DATE_TO 
  AND b.DATE_TO NOT BETWEEN :GIVEN_DATE_FROM AND :GIVEN_DATE_TO
```